# error in the query, i dont know what's the issue?

Tags: php

```
if (count($errors) == 0) {
    //$password = md5($password_1);//encrypt the password before saving in the database

    $query = "INSERT INTO camp (partcipant_name, partcipant_fname, partcipant_email , candidate's_civil_id, father's_civil_id, participant_age, education_level, school_name, school_address, principal's_name, school's_contact_number, candidates_mobile_phone, fathers_mobile_phone, participant_gender) 
              VALUES('$partiname', '$fathname', $cemail, '$candicivil', '$fathcivil', '$cage', '$canedu','$schlname','$schladdre', '$priname', '$scholpno', '$cpno', '$fpno', '$partigen')";
    mysql_query($query); 
    $_SESSION['partcipant_name'] = $partiname;
    $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
   header('location: makersacademy.net');
   echo mysql_error();
}
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''s_civil_id, father's_civil_id, participant_age, education_level, school_name, s' at line 1

Comment: [edit] your question and add error text.

Comment: Avoid using single quotes in the table name.

Comment: `father's_civil_id` is __incorrect__ field name, it should be changes or excaped with `\``.

Comment: You can't use `candidate's_civil_id` with `'` as a field name. Use something like `candidate_civil_id`